# How to make slider in unity show up in code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a slider in Unity, I want to change it's value in a script, it doesn't show up. I can't make a slider variable, I try to make one like the Unity documentation and C# says the syntax is wrong. How can I fix this?

```
//What should work:

private slider x;

//C# says the slider class doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to watch out for case sensitivity. There is no `slider` class but there is a `Slider` class.  You also need to import `UnityEngine.UI` when using UI elements.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

private Slider mySlider;
```